# Implement a stored PL/SQL procedure

Tags: plsql

Task 2 (5.0 marks)
Stored PL/SQL procedure
Implement a stored PL/SQL procedure PARTSUPPLIER that lists information
about the supplier key and supplier name supplying parts. The procedure first
computes the total number of suppliers supplying the specified part. The
procedure then extracts the supplier’s information supplying the specified part.
The information to be displayed include the part key, part name, the supplier
key and the supplier’s name. An example of a segment of the output for the
list of suppliers supplying a specified part (part 59396) is as follow:
part key: 59396, orange cream sandy lavender drab
Number of suppliers supplying the part: 4

```
supplier Key supplier Name
 166 Supplier#000000166
 935 Supplier#000000935
 1704 Supplier#000001704
 2397 Supplier#000002397
```

It is up to you to decide if you want to handle exception in your procedure.
Deliverables
Submit your spooled file solution2.lst (or solution2.pdf) that contains your SQL script
and the output from the execution of the script. The report must have no errors
related to the implementation of your task and it must list all PL/SQL and SQL
statements processed.
Remember to set ECHO option of SQL*Plus to ON!

Comment: Please show sample data, expected result, show what you tried so far and ask what exactly you still need to know.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't going to do your homework. Focus your question on what you have tried and the error you are getting, with a minimum reproducible example. If you don't know how to implement some task on your part of the code, ask about that, again, with a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

At least provide some sample data to check the issue

Comment: This is an old question (7 years old) and your answer has already been provided by other answers. You are not adding new information.

Comment: I see...I noticed that it was showing as asked 4 days ago so I asked for details. Anyways, thanks for reminding me. I have newly joined so I was a bit careless.  I will be careful not to repeat the answer in the future.

Comment: This is weird, my comment was done in another thread where you provided a duplicated answer to an old question, I'm sure that the comment was done in the other thread, but now I'm seeing it in this other answer and the original one shows no comment ¯\_(ツ)_/¯